# What is the idiomatic way of ending this Python loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

[image]

I'm learning how to use Bokeh for data science which creates wonderful and rich visualizations. However, I'm coming up short when trying to find a way to end this Python loop in the browser. I'm pretty sure it's because I'm not read the bokeh documentation correctly which is why I'm here ask for help. If the animation is only 100 frames how do I tell the browser to stop looping and perhaps end the session?

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Select, TextInput
from bokeh.layouts import row, column

import numpy as np

webinstance = curdoc()
index = 1
def modify_doc(doc):
    N=100
    X = np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, N)
    Y = 0.5 * np.sin(3 * X)

    p = figure(plot_height=500, plot_width=1000, title="Test", x_range=(-2*np.pi,2*np.pi), y_range=(-0.6,0.6))

    ypts = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[X[0]], y=[Y[0]]))

    p.circle(x="x", y="y", size=9, source=ypts)

    def update():
        global index 
        new_data = dict(x=[X[index]], y=[Y[index]])
        ypts.stream(new_data)
        index += 1

    doc.add_periodic_callback(update, 40)
    doc.add_root(p)

modify_doc(webinstance)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bokeh is in some ways not always exactly idiomatic Python. The reason for this is simply that Bokeh is not *only* a Python library, it is also (mostly, in fact) a JavaScript runtime. Sometimes requirements on one side affect things on the other.

In any case, `add_periodic_callback` starts a callback that runs forever, at the specified interval. To stop it, you will need to explicitly call `remove_periodic_callback(callback_id)`. You could do this from inside `update` after some counter expires (or whatever other condition you want to stop things happens).

Alterntatively, you could try adding a fixed number of callbacks at increasing intervals "up front" like [this old example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/0.11.1/examples/app/timeout.py) though I am not sure I would recommend that approach normally.

Comment: I've been through bryan's git carefully but haven't seen this example before and appreciate the link. I'm just running it into the code now but am wondering what are the reasons for your hesitation in recommending this approach?

Comment: Well, it's an old example that was removed some time ago, because most viewers seemed confused about its purpose (which was just to demo `add_timeout_callback`). Maybe my admonishment was too harsh, but I do think it has more assumptions and hence more limited applicability. You'd have to know exactly how many runs you want up front, compute exacty when they all should be, and there probably should not be too many of them (hundreds, but maybe not thousands?)

Comment: It's also, just in the sense of abstract programming concepts and clarity, less obviously related to "looping".